# How to execute part of a script just in the first attempt?

Tags: exe

There is a script which later I'm going to convert it in to .exe.

The code consists of two main parts. when I run the exe file for the first time, I want it to execute thoroughly. However in later attempts I just need it to run first part of the code.

How can I accomplish this very purpose?

Comment: Why not put a `is_run_once=False` before the first part, set it to True in the first part and have an if statement, which checks it?

Comment: create a .txt and store some information in it, and mark it in your first run.

Answer (score 0):

I thank you, guys.

I created a txt file and in the first line of it I wrote "False".

in the second part of the code I used an if statement for checking if it is "False" and inside of the if block changed it to "True".
So that part of the code executes only in the first attempt.